# How can the generators of subalgebra $\mathfrak g^{\sigma}$ of $\sigma$-stable elements be expressed through generators of Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be the semisimple Lie algebra of type $D_{4}$. Let $\sigma$ be the 3-rd order automorphism of $\mathfrak g$ induced by the triality of $D_{4}$:

[image]
$$
\sigma:\alpha_{1}\mapsto\alpha_{3}\mapsto\alpha_{4},\alpha_{2}\mapsto\alpha_{2}
$$

Let $\mathfrak g^{\sigma}$ be the subalgebra of $\sigma$-stable elements of $\mathfrak g$.

How can Serre generators of $\mathfrak g^{\sigma}$ be expressed through Serre generators of $\mathfrak g$?

I suppose that "Serre generators", "Serre-Chevalley generators", and "Chevalley generators" are equivalent terms. (In my opinion, perhaps the use of a Chevalley basis would be more straightforward?)

Comment: I think that you will find all the information you need in this case in Levasseur, T.; Smith, S. P.
Primitive ideals and nilpotent orbits in type G2.
J. Algebra 114 (1988), no. 1, 81–105.

Comment: @BuloisMichael Thanks. Somehow, I'm not surprised that one of the authors is from UPMC. :-)

Comment: @BuloisMichael Indeed, quite enlightening. Perhaps you can post it as an answer so I can select it as best answer.

Comment: @Jake: It's a good idea to look also at the careful treatment of fixed point subalgebras under graph automorphisms in Section 9.5 of Roger Carter's book *Lie Algebras of Finite and Affine Type* (Cambridge, 2005), including the choice of basis under a graph automorphism.  Carter's book is also useful because he later generalizes many of the ideas to affine Lie algebras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the G$_2$ case, I think that you will find all the information you need in Levasseur, T.; Smith, S. P. Primitive ideals and nilpotent orbits in type G2. J. Algebra 114 (1988), no. 1, 81–105.

Things can also be viewed in a very nice symmetric way using 4-ality. See Section 3.4 of 
J. Landsberg and L. Manivel, Representation theory and projective geometry.
In: Algebraic transformation groups and algebraic varieties, Enc.
Math. Sci., 132, Springer-Verlag, 2004, 131-167.

Comment: It's worth pointing out an online link to the first reference (in response to pressure, Elsevier is making older journal articles freely available now): http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869388902141